# What is filename for SMS-sent images processed by Twilio?

Tags: image, twilio, twilio-studio

When I send an SMS to my Twilio number which includes an image, there doesn't appear to be a filename associated with the image.

I'm using Twilio Studio.

**Example:**

- Send an SMS text with image to my *Twilio number*
- A Twilio Studio Flow pipes the `{{trigger.message.MediaUrl0}}` and sends an SMS text sent to my *actual phone number*
- The URL is of the following format `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<long-GUID-1>/Messages/<long-GUID-2>/Media/<long-GUID-3>`
- Clicking on this URL opens a browser pointing to a translated URL `https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/media.twiliocdn.com/<long-GUID-1>/<long-GUID-4>` and showing the original image
- **But no filename.**

I'm trying to access the filename so I can apply a naming convention to it. How is this accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL to download the actual media is dynamically generated.

You can refer to the blog post here:

[Retrieving Twilio MMS Image URLs with Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/retrieving-twilio-mms-image-urls-with-node-js)

Comment: Thank you for the resource. How is this done using Twilio Studio? I don't see a widget for running NodeJS.

Comment: Well you have access to the MediaURL using Liquid Syntax, so you can pull of the URL there.

How do I use Liquid with Twilio Studio?
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4413699936411-How-do-I-use-Liquid-with-Twilio-Studio-

It will allow you to pull the Metadata send into your Studio Flow. You can view the Studio Execution logs to see the format you need to access using that Liquid Syntax.

Comment: Hm. I see that the MediaURL is accessible (per the original post), but there is no filename in either the Twilio internal URL nor the AWS CDN URL. Or at least not a filename that I can see (no file *extension*; .jpg, .png, etc.).

Comment: I just found the `Run Function` Widget. I'll explore that. Thanks again!